# Excel Linest function to handle patchy data?

Tags: excel, regression

I have a set of data I try to extract a linear function from. If I plot a scatter plot I get a nice function I can display, but then need to manually extract the slope and intercept from the displayed equation.

Linest() should help me, however, as soon as a #NA or empty cell is included I get an #VALUE error. How can I handle this problem? I tried to include iferror and use an array function but without success

Thanks

Comment: @pnuts yes, but then I need to read it off and enter it into the code. I want new data to update the function parameters and automatically update the model.

Comment: Use the `SLOPE` and `INTERCEPT` functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to get around blanks/errors by using an array formula and checking if the value is a number.

For example, if my known y's are:
12, 22, , 53, 78

and they are in cells E7:E11

Then I can use the following formula:

```
{=LINEST(IF(ISNUMBER(E7:E11),E7:E11,E7))}
```

Where the curly braces are added automatically when you hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter to confirm the array formula

This results in a gradient of 16.3, which is equivalent to the gradient of a trendline added to a scatter graph of the data above

Please let me know if that helps

Comment: Hi maxhob! thanks for the help, I was using iferror but if(isnumber()) actually works.
however, I want this formula to take in a range of blank cells, so a use can enter more data in the future and the slope/intercept updates. Isnumber(<blank cell>) would return FALSE, yet the results change with the blank cells included


`{=INDEX(LINEST(IF(ISNUMBER(B35:BA35),B35:BA35,B35),IF(ISNUMBER(B10:BA10), B10:BA10,B10)),1)}` yields a different slope than
if the range is only extended to column M instead of BA.

Comment: also, why is the return value if false the first cell? (E7 in your example)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (but surely not the best) to this problem was to create another row checking for errors and containing `TRUE` or `FALSE` accordingly. (`B11:BA11` in the example below.)

The `if` function then evaluates if the number is to be taken or not. if not it is replaced by the `average` of all values to give an approximation.

`{=SLOPE(IF(B11:BA11,B36:BA36,AVERAGE(IF(B11:BA11,B36:BA36,""))),IF(B11:BA11, B10:BA10,AVERAGE(IF(B11:BA11,B10:BA10,""))))}`